# Determine which sets $E \subset\mathbb{N}$ satisfy $E'=\mathbb{N}$

Tags: general-topology

My idea is to separate into two cases. Show that $E$ is finite so $E'$ is finite and then $E \ne \mathbb{N}$.

And show that $E$ is infinite so the $\mathbb{N} \subset E '$.

$E'$ is the set of accumulation points of $E$.

The point is, I don't know how to show it.

Comment: Is $E'$ the closure of $E$?

Comment: @QED I believe $E^{'}$ is the set of all acumulation points of $E$.

Comment: One needs to specify what topology they are talking about

Comment: The topology is $A_{n}$ =$ \{k \in \mathbb{N} : k \ge n\}$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: I would start by showing that if $n\in\Bbb N$, the open nbhds of $n$ are the sets $A_k$ for $k\le n$: then you can easily determine whether every open nbhd of $n$ intersects a given set $E$.

Clearly $\varnothing'=\varnothing$, so assume that $E\ne\varnothing$. If $E$ is finite, let $m=\max E$ and show that $E'=\{n\in\Bbb N:n\le m\}$. If $E$ is infinite, show that for each $n\in\Bbb N$ there is an $e\in E$ such that $e\ge n$, and use that to show that $E'=\Bbb N$.